# Wrong answer on kattis problem: texture analysis

Tags: loops, rust, iterator, iteration

I recently tried to do the online programming challenge Texture Analysis on open.kattis.com; however, despite my answers for the sample cases being correct in my personal tests, I keep getting the second sample case wrong, the status of the submission says: "wrong answer". What am I doing wrong with my code?

[Link to  the kattis problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/textureanalysis). My code:

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead};
fn main() {
    let mut line: i8 = 0; 
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for input in stdin.lock().lines().map(|l| l.unwrap()) {
        line += 1;
        if input == "END" {
            break;
        }
        let pattern = input
            .split("*")
            .filter(|&i| i.contains("."))
            .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
        let c = pattern
            .iter()
            .all(|j| j.len() == pattern[0].len());
        if (c && pattern.len() != 1 ) || pattern.len() == 0 {
            println!("{} EVEN", line);
        } else {
            println!("{} NOT EVEN", line);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed commented example:

```rust
use std::io::{self, BufRead};

fn main() {
    // line needs to store values up to 2000
    // it cannot be an i8, must be an u16 at minimum
    // Rust's default for integer literals is i32 which we use here
    let mut line = 0;
    let stdin = io::stdin();
    for input in stdin.lock().lines().map(|l| l.unwrap()) {
        line += 1;
        if input == "END" {
            break;
        }
        // not possible to construct NON-EVEN input in <= 3 chars
        if input.len() <= 3 {
            println!("{} EVEN", line);
            continue;
        }
        // ignore first & last * when splitting input
        let pattern = &input[1..input.len()-1]
            .split("*")
            // do not filter out empty strings
            .collect::<Vec<&str>>();
        let space_len = pattern[0].len();
        let is_even = pattern
            .iter()
            .all(|j| j.len() == space_len);
        if is_even {
            println!("{} EVEN", line);
        } else {
            println!("{} NOT EVEN", line);
        }
    }
}
```